# Listview button id changed on scrolling listview Android

Tags: android, android-listview, listadapter, android-adapter, custom-adapter

In my android application i am using `Listview` which will have button and textview. Here, I am changing button icon on button click. I have used customAdapter for listview. The functionality of changing button icon is working perfectly.

The problem is that, when i scroll my listview, the icon of other button also gets changed.
I don't know what is the problem with my code.Please help me to solve this issue.

customAdapter :

public class CustomListViewAdapter_ringtone extends
        ArrayAdapter {

```
Context context;
public static MediaPlayer mp = null;
int btnId;
String rowTag;
View previouView = null;
ListView mListView;

public CustomListViewAdapter_ringtone(Context context, int resourceId,
        List<RowItem_ringtone> items, ListView lst) {
    super(context, resourceId, items);
    this.context = context;
    this.mListView = lst;
}

private class ViewHolder {
    TextView txtTitle;
    ImageButton btnPlay;
    ImageButton btnSet;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    final RowItem_ringtone rowItem = getItem(position);

    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.ringtone_row, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.ringtoneTitle);
        holder.btnPlay = (ImageButton) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
        holder.btnSet = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnSet);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.txtTitle.setText(rowItem.getRingTitle());
    holder.btnPlay.setTag(rowItem.getRingId());
    holder.btnSet.setTag(rowItem.getRingId());

    holder.btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if (CustomListViewAdapter_ringtone.mp != null) {
                if (CustomListViewAdapter_ringtone.mp.isPlaying()) {
                    CustomListViewAdapter_ringtone.mp.stop();
                    CustomListViewAdapter_ringtone.mp.release();
                    CustomListViewAdapter_ringtone.mp = null;
                }
            }
            if (previouView != null) {
                if (previouView != v) {

                    previouView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play_icon);
                    v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pause_icon);
                    CustomListViewAdapter_ringtone.mp = MediaPlayer.create(
                            getContext(),
                            Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().toString()));
                    CustomListViewAdapter_ringtone.mp.start();
                    previouView = v;
                } else {
                    previouView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play_icon);
                    previouView = null;
                }
            } else {
                CustomListViewAdapter_ringtone.mp = MediaPlayer.create(
                        getContext(),
                        Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().toString()));
                CustomListViewAdapter_ringtone.mp.start();
                v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pause_icon);
                previouView = v;
            }
        }
    });

    holder.btnSet.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String name = rowItem.getRingTitle();
            name = "one_direction_" + name.toLowerCase().replace(" ", "_");

            Uri path = Uri.parse("android.resource://"
                    + getContext().getPackageName() + "/raw/" + name);

            RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(getContext(),
                    RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, path);

            RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getContext(), path).play();
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), name + " is set as ringtone.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }
    });
    return convertView;
}
```

}

Comment: where are you defining previouView?

Comment: i am defining `previousView` outside `getView()` method and inside my class.

Comment: @zanky include the **previousview** in viewholder.

Comment: @Yugesh can u please suggest change in mycode ?

Comment: @zanky you have the **previousview** in each row i think.

Comment: @Yugesh i edited my code. Will u please refer it ?

Comment: @zanky where is the previous view will display.it'll display in each row means.you can set an tag for that.

Comment: "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18076350/using-buttons-in-listview-row-android?noredirect=1#comment26456281_18076350" here is a link, why i used previousView.

Comment: I am using previousView, to check whether the user is clicking button of same row or different row. And according to that, i am changing their icon.

Comment: @zanky you want change the row background color or button bg.

Comment: @Yugesh Yes, to change background image i used previousView. But now, if i scroll that list then background color of other button also gets changed. So, how to solve this issue ?

Comment: @zanky change the convert view bg.then you get correctly.

Comment: @Yugesh can u please suggest change in my code? I am not getting, what changes i should make.

Comment: @zanky till i didn't understand little bit what you want.Add simple image what you want about that list(for better under standing). i will try and give code for you or i will suggest where to change your code.

Comment: @Yugesh ok..give code or suggest any change.

Answer (score 0):

Your customized list view like below image but with button, if you click the button change the selected row image and also change the paly button icon correct.

[image]

Comment: Yes, your guess is correct, but i am not getting where i should make change in my code.

Comment: @zanky in getview method you assign variable **convertView** for view.Change all the **previousview** into **convertView** till you didnt get means say i will explain through base adapter concept.

Comment: I am using prviousView to maintain state. So, where i need to change?

Comment: @zanky when you click first song to highlight first one and click third song means you want  highlight 1st and 3rd song.

Comment: @Zanky post your songs array details.

Comment: I think, you got me wrong. If i click first song, button icon of that row should be changed to "pause" and if I click 3rd song, the icon of 1st row is changed to "play" and icon of 3rd row is changed to "pause". All these works fine but the problem is that if i scroll a list, then icon of "pause" is set for other button. All these happens due to list recycling. So, i don't know hoe to solve it.

Comment: @Zanky i think your list view getting shuffle.

Comment: Items are not shuffled, only id is changed.

Comment: @zanky k I'll try it your code in my machine.one get correct result.I'll post the code.